# What's Wrong With My App Description?

Tags: android, keyword-search, popularity

It's been over a month but still my app Couldn't be searched with its Full Name.
It is really frustating. This way, my app would never be visible. When Full name is written, then my app is coming at 26th position and some apps which don't have any relation with name are coming at top. What Should i do? I couldn't search my app with keywords popular to Photography Section. Somebody, please help me...

Link to the app is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sagar.mehar.camera2

Comment: The results are sorted by many factors such as votes and downloads, not sure what you are looking for as a solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google play store uses a number of variables such as download numbers, ratings, app description etc. for ranking apps while searching for a keyword. This means that even if your title has an exact match, your app need not be the first in search results.

Here are some strategies that can help.

1. Ensure that your app is of high quality and hence people who install it retain and rate it well.
2. Link to your app page if you have your own site.
3. Improve your app description page to have more relevant content as to the features in your app.

You can also promote your app through Google adwords or Facebook. If your app is useful to people, it will gradually pick up new users and it will improve your app's position in search results.